# Find dy/dt= Sin (tan (9t-7))

Tags: calculus

$y = \sin (\tan (9t-7))$, find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ 
Stuck with the steps and could use a hand with the right place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=\sin s$ where $s=\tan u$ and  $u=9t-7.$ Then by chain rule,

$dy/dt=(dy/ds). (ds/du). (du/dt)=\cos(\tan(9t-7)). \sec^2(9t-7).9.$

Answer (score 0):

Peel the thing like an onion. From the outside going in.

Replace $\tan (9t-7)=u$

Then by the chain rule the derivative is:

$\cos (u) \cdot \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} u$

$=\cos (\tan (9t-7)) \cdot \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} \tan(9t-7)$

The second part is easy. Just apply the chain rule again.

$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} \tan(9t-7)=9\sec^2 (9t-7)$

Hence the full derivative in all its glory is:

$\boxed{9\cos (\tan (9t-7)) \cdot \sec^2 (9t-7)}$

Just remember the trick. Peel that function.